# who calculated for the first time the volume of a cylinder? How?

Tags: mathematics

I need the details please. I have been searching information about that but I can't find something useful.

Comment: It seems rather obvious once the area of a circle has been calculated: the volume of any prism is the area base times the height. Why do you think there are details on those two discoveries?

Comment: Well, Euclid's *Elements* have facts about volumes of cylinders.  But not what we, nowadays, would call "calculated the volume of a cylinder".  Archimedes was proud of his proof relating the volume of a sphere with the volume of the circumscribed cylinder. But, again, we presumably would not say he "calculated the volume of a cylinder".

Answer (score 2):

The question is not well defined. That the volume of the cylinder equals to the product of the area of the base and height is pretty evident, and once a rigorous theory of volume was stated, the proof is immediate. This is contained in Euclid, for example. But this only reduces the volume of the cylinder to the area of the disk. For the area of the disk it was known to Euclid that it is proportional to 
the square of the radius. And also equals (1/2) times radius times circumference.
The coefficient of proportionality is called $\pi$. Same number $\pi$ you need to
calculate the circumference.
This number $\pi$ cannot be
"calculated". One can only approximate it. For example, Archimedes approximated it to 5 digits, while the modern mathematicians with the help of a computer obtained about one billion digits. But that's about all one can do.